# Automatically name anonymous functions with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, anonymous-function

I am working on a regular expression substitution that automatically names anonymous functions in a Javascript file.

Until now I've come up with this regex:

```
/^(\s*)(?!window\.)(\w+\.)?(\w+)(\s*)([:=])(\s*)function(\s*)\(/gm
```

that correctly names functions (and preservers spacing) except the ones that are on the `window` object or that are referenced in an array (`this.foo[i] : function() {}`).

The problem is that this regex doesn't match functions specified as vars, like this:

```
var foo = function() {}
```

This is a regex online tester with my regex so far https://regex101.com/r/gI3dH5/3

Any help?

Comment: Use http://esprima.org/ for parsing js files.

Comment: This is for a search/replace I perform directly into PHPStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i got it :D

`^(\s*)((?!\s*window\.)|(var))(\s*)(\w+\.)?(\w+)(\s*)([:=])(\s*)function(\s*)\(`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(\s*)((?!window\\.)|(var))(\s*)(\w+\\.)?(\w+)(\s*)([:=])(\s*)function(\s*)\\(
```

Comment: That doesn't seems to work (aside from the missing `\` before the last parenthesis), it matches also the line with `window`, which I don't want to be matched.

Comment: Now it's really close, it still misses the case where `window` is not at the start of the string (see https://regex101.com/r/gI3dH5/5)

Comment: `^(\s*)((?!\s*window\.)|(var))(\s*)(\w+\.)?(\w+)(\s*)([:=])(\s*)function(\s*)\(`

Comment: I think we have a winner ^_^

@marcel: would you mind adding a new answer so I can accept it?